# Could any kind of code be stored on an external server?

Tags: php, website, html

is it possible to story any code (php html js css ...) on

```
someserver.com/code.file
```

and request it to be loaded onto any website like

```
mysite.com
```

thanks

Comment: Your question is really unclear!! More details are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, with the correct setup. This is exactly how many PHP exploits work. Which is why you **shouldn't do/allow it**.